pylanceがtomlの型情報を認識しない
python 3.12.4
pylance v2024.2.3
tomllibを使ってtomlをロードし､値を変数にセットしたとき
pylanceがこの値の型をanyとしてしか見てくれません
tomllib(や他のパーサー)のドキュメントを見ても､パーサーは自動的に値を
pythonの型に変換すると書いているように思われます
toml_str = """
python-version = "3.11.0"
python-implementation = "CPython"
"""
data = tomllib.loads(toml_str)
v = data['python-version']

としたとき､vにマウスを合わせると (variable) v: any になってしまいます
手動でpylanceに型情報を与えてやらなければならないのでしょうか


tomllib(や他のパーサー)のドキュメントを見ても､パーサーは自動的に値をpythonの型に変換すると書いているように思われます

toml_str = """
python-version = 3.11
python-implementation = "CPython"
"""

とするとdata['python-version']はfloat型の値になって、data['python-implementation']は文字列型の値になります。
「自動的に値をpythonの型に変換する」はこの意味です。これと「式の型が推論される」を混同していると思います。
また、「自動的に値をpythonの型に変換する」からこそdataのvalue側の式の型はAnyになるのです。
data[key]で取り出せる値はstrかもしれないしfloatかもしれないしintかもしれないしlistかもしれないしdictかもしれません。だって「自動的に値をpythonの型に変換する」のですから。

手動でpylanceに型情報を与えてやらなければならないのでしょうか

はい。そうです。
